# Laravel 5 Application Key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am new to Laravel. I just started it tonight. Actually, I have the following code:

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),
```

In *xampp/htdocs/laravel/blog/config/app.php*.
I want to change this key to 32-bit by cmd as:

```
xampp\htdocs\laravel/blog>php artisan key:generate
```

It generates the key but could not replace/update in *xampp/htdocs/laravel/blog/config/app.php*.

Comment: Do you have the .env file in place? if so, please check if you have a key in there.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Brown I got it from there,Thank you.

Comment: I added one new answer, just to emphasize on users passwords.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

This line in your `app.php`, `'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),`, is saying that the key for your application can be found in your `.env` file on the line `APP_KEY`.

Basically it tells Laravel to look for the key in the `.env` file first and if there isn't one there then to use `'SomeRandomString'`.

When you use the `php artisan key:generate` it will generate the new key to your `.env` file and not the `app.php` file.

*As kotapeter said, your `.env` will be inside your root Laravel directory and may be hidden; xampp/htdocs/laravel/blog*

Answer (score 102):

**You can generate a `key` by the following command:**

```
php artisan key:generate
```

The key will be written automatically in your `.env` file.

```
APP_KEY=YOUR_GENERATED_KEY
```

If you want to see your `key` after generation use `--show` option

```
php artisan key:generate --show
```

*Note: The `.env` is a hidden file in your project folder.*

[image]

Comment: line gets updated automatically when run the command if u have the default  empty line already APP_KEY =

Answer (score 45):

Just as another option if you want to print only the key (doesn't write the .env file) you can use:

```
php artisan key:generate --show
```

Comment: this should be default? Otherwise when you type php artisan key:generate don't you hose the passwords in your (hopefully development) machine? IE we need php artisan key:generate --write

Comment: @TomAndersen No, APP_KEY is only used for encryption (so, by default, cookies), NOT for password hashing. I thought https://tighten.co/blog/app-key-and-you was a nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

From the line

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),
```

`APP_KEY` is a global environment variable that is present inside the `.env` file.

You can replace the application key if you trigger

```
php artisan key:generate
```

command. This will always generate the new key.

The output may be like this:

---

```
Application key [Idgz1PE3zO9iNc0E3oeH3CHDPX9MzZe3] set successfully.
```

---

```
Application key [base64:uynE8re8ybt2wabaBjqMwQvLczKlDSQJHCepqxmGffE=] set successfully.
```

Base64 encoding should be the default in Laravel 5.4

Note that when you first create your Laravel application, key:generate is automatically called.

#### If you change the key be aware that passwords saved with `Hash::make()` will no longer be valid.

Comment: "If you change the key be aware that passwords saved with Hash::make() will no longer be valid." - That's something that I thought, too. I also read this quite often on the internet. However, if you have a look at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Hashing/HashServiceProvider.php and https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php and the past versions of this code, the app key is not used to salt the hash or for anything else. I tried changing the app key and, like the code suggests, my password is still checked correctly.

Comment: Application key is used to encrypt session data, rather than passwords, which is mentioned in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation#configuration) and in addition, at least from my understanding, it assumes symmetic decryptable encryption.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was in that I had not yet ran `composer update` for this new **project/fork**. The command failed silently, nothing happened.

After running `composer update` it worked.

Comment: You may mean `composer install`. You shouldn't necessarily be running `composer update` immediately on a new fork of a project, unless you actually want to be updating dependencies.