# Is it necessary to execute "php artisan key:generate" command after installation of laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, key-generator

I have installed **laravel 5.7** in my system. I want to know that is it necessary to execute `php artisan key:generate` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> php artisan key:generate

This command sets the `APP_KEY` value in your `.env` file.

If you create a project with composer it'll generated default with project.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel
```

If you clone project using `git clone` some folder is ignored by git so you might not get env file as well as vendor folder. Therefore, they will have to manually enter `php artisan key:generate` for their app to function correctly.

So, TL:DR the only time you *need* to call `php artisan key:generate` is following a `clone` of a pre-created Laravel project.

**Note:** If you try to run a Laravel project with your `APP_KEY` set to `SomeRandomString` (which is the default in your `.env.example` file, you will actually get an error:

> No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not always necessary** to execute the `php artisan key: generated` command after the installation time.

---

1. If you get this error then you must run this command: `php artisan key: generated`

   > RuntimeException No application encryption key has been specified.

   - `php artisan key:generate` This will generate a random key for `APP_KEY` in `.env` file
2. If you have not received this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839648/no-application-encryption-key-has-been-specified) then you do not need to worry about `APP_KEY`, because If you install Laravel via Composer, this key has already been set for you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run that command in a fresh install of laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is necessary to execute:

```
 php artisan key:generate
```

Refer this link for futher information:
   [Laravel 5 Application Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700580/laravel-5-application-key)

I hope this will help you..

Comment: Thanks for your answer but laravel installation is already done this thing than why we need to execute this command.