# Laravel - Why laravel ask to rename .env.example to .env while .env already exist?

Tags: laravel, documentation

In Laravel 6 [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/installation#configuration) second paragraph of `Application Key` written like this

> Typically, this string should be 32 characters long. The key can be
>   set in the .env environment file. If you have not renamed the
>   `.env.example` file to `.env`, you should do that now. If the application
>   key is not set, your user sessions and other encrypted data will not
>   be secure!

Why did they ask to rename it? I also found this paragraph in the Laravel older version. Is there any difference between those since they have the same content but different name?

Comment: if you already have an `.env` file you don't need to rename the `.env.example` file. they are identical at the very beginning. if you don't have an  `.env` file, in that case you have to rename it to `.env` as your application environment will be loaded from `.env` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've install Laravel using composer command.

> composer create-project laravel/laravel projectname

you don't need renamed the `.env.example` file to `.env`. If you installed Laravel via Composer or the Laravel installer, this key has already been set for you by the `php artisan key:generate` command.

If you clone project using `git clone` some folder is ignored by git so you might not get env file as well as vendor folder. Therefore, they will have to manually enter `php artisan key:generate` for their app to function correctly.

[More info SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58056254/9978078)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel need to use `.env` file to define a database connection, some general setting like `application key` as well. So if you have no `.env` file, your Laravel has not a setting for now.

Like they said, `If the application key is not set, your user sessions and other encrypted data will not be secure!` You need to *create / copy /remove* the `.env.example` to the new `.env` for this reason. for letting our Laravel knows about general config.

By the way, do not use the `.env.example` like copy-and-paste because it's an example. you need to change the value config to your own.

Answer (score 0):

The `.env.example` the file is just an example of the `.env` file. It is not used by the app. It is used to serve as a base for you to edit and rename.

In a fresh Laravel installation, the root directory of your application will contain a `.env.example` file. If you install Laravel **via Composer**, this file will automatically be renamed to `.env`. Otherwise, you should rename the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is move it on your `server` with `Filezilla` or another FTP program. `Rename file`, and `re-download` it on your `computer`. It works for me last time :)