# My env gets deleted whenever new release is pushed in a Laravel AWS pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

1. I installed a Laravel project on AWS Elastic Beanstalk
2. I created an env on the server
3. I run `php artisan key:generate` command and filled all my env variables

This works fine and my application starts. But then I push some other work on my server through my CI pipeline, but it automatically deletes the env file.

Also note that I have already added my env in .gitignore so it's not pushing my env.

I think it's because Elastic Beanstalk automatically deletes old files and create new files whenever new build is released.

following is my script section of composer.json:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Laravel with `composer`? Are you receiving the following error: `RuntimeException No application encryption key has been specified.`? If you are using composer key generation is likely being taken care of automatically for you via `post-create-project-cmd` or similar. [See here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58056361/1720873)

Comment: yes this error is shown but because env gets deleted so naturally app key is deleted as well. can you tell me how i can stop env from being deleted?

Comment: Are you using `composer`? If so, can you update your question to include an example of the `scripts` section of your `composer.json` file? It should include an entry similar to this: `"post-create-project-cmd": ["php artisan key:generate"]`. [You can learn more about composer scripts here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md)

Comment: yes i am including my composer file script section in my question @dusthaines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I need to either create the env every time I make a new release or I can set env variables in `ebextension config settings` given by AWS, so I ended up setting env variables to a config file inside ebextension.

So it is normal that, whenever you send a new release through a pipeline, the env is deleted since it's included in git ignore.